# HTML "multiple" for multiple select box options are not identifying click as well as delegate function of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using html `multiple` for multiple select box dropdown.
on click of any option, I do add css class `permissionsSelection` which changes its background color to yellow, to show selected option.
If selected option clicked again it get unselected and class `permissionsSelection` removes

**CSS**

```
.permissionsSelection{
   background:yellow;
 }
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#availablePermissions").delegate(".permissions", "click", function(e) {

        if($(this).hasClass("permissionsSelection")){
            $(this).removeClass("permissionsSelection");
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass("permissionsSelection");
        }

    });
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="multipleSelectBox" multiple name="availablePermissionsEdit"  id="availablePermissionsEdit">                              <option id="itemId1Edit1" value="option1" class="permissions">option1</option>
<option id="itemId1Edit2" value="option2" class="permissions">option2</option>                                          <option id="itemId1Edit3" value="option3" class="permissions">option3</option>      
</select>
```

This working fine in all browsers. As usual not working in **IE8**.

on click delegate function doesnt fire , i had also tried live , on and click in place of delegate but none of them working for me .

please help save me from IE

Comment: If you want to save urself from IE delete it from your system

Comment: lol .. thats project requirement :(

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jQuery version v1.10.2

Comment: options don't fire mouse events in some browsers, mainly Chrome an IE, so attaching mouse events to option elements are generally a bad idea if you want cross browser support.

Comment: Any solution to this question will involve using an event other than .click.

Comment: Also, changing the selects background color doesn't remove the blue default color of the `::selection`

Comment: Changing the class is easy enough -> http://jsfiddle.net/cDQv6/, but background color is not the same as the selection color for the selected option

Comment: thanks adeneo , kevin ..that was help full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE borwser select > option click event dose not work, if you want to implement then please use selected value for targeted event, please try this code

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $("#availablePermissionsEdit").on("click", function(e) { 
     $target = $(this).find("option[value="+this.value+"]");
     if ($target.hasClass("permissionsSelection")) {
         $target.removeClass("permissionsSelection");
     }else {
         $target.addClass("permissionsSelection");
    }
 });
```

});

**NOTE** Please make sure the option value should unique.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ek73m/2/)

Comment: this fiddle site demo not working on IE8.. page got messed up

Comment: @mayank Fiddle will not work in ie8, can you download latest jquery and fiddle code on your local system and run in ie8

Comment: $target = $(this).find("option[value="+this.value+"]"); thats a nice trick.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45173/discussion-between-girish-jangid-and-mayank)